# What is Imagemagick relationship to imagick?

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagemagick, imagick

It seem that I don't have imagemagick package installed. My confusion is how does my php imagick work without Imagemagick installed? I thought the two work in tandem as requirement as imagick is only a PHP api.

```
root@se /usr/share/doc # dpkg --get-selections | grep imagemagick
imagemagick-6-common                            install
root@se /usr/share/doc # dpkg --get-selections | grep imagick
plesk-php73-imagick                             install
plesk-php74-imagick                             install
root@se /usr/share/doc # dpkg -L imagemagick-6-common
/.
/etc
/etc/ImageMagick-6
/etc/ImageMagick-6/coder.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/colors.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/delegates.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/log.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/magic.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/mime.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/quantization-table.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/thresholds.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/type-apple.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/type-dejavu.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/type-ghostscript.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/type-windows.xml
/etc/ImageMagick-6/type.xml
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/ImageMagick-6
/usr/share/ImageMagick-6/english.xml
/usr/share/ImageMagick-6/francais.xml
/usr/share/ImageMagick-6/locale.xml
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/imagemagick-6-common
/usr/share/bug/imagemagick-6-common/presubj
/usr/share/bug/imagemagick-6-common/script
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/README.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/copyright
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/html
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/html/README
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagick uses ImageMagick. Imagick is an API that makes calls to ImageMagick. So when you install Imagick, either it will install ImageMagick for you or you have to install ImageMagick first.  See

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

You can check if ImageMagick is installed by checking the version:

```
<?php
exec("convert -version",$out,$returnval);
foreach($out as $text)
{echo "$text<br>";}
?>
```

or you can search to see if installed and where:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
system("which -a convert");  
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

If you think you have ImageMagick 7, then try

```
<?php
exec("magick -version",$out,$returnval);
foreach($out as $text)
{echo "$text<br>";}
?>
```

and/or

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
system("which -a magick");  
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

You should also check your Imagick info at

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: Imagemagick package does not show up in dpkg as shown. How can I find out definitely if the Imagemagick package is installed and where? thanks.

Comment: See my additions in my answer

Comment: `root@s1 /usr/games # convert -version

-bash: convert: command not found`


phpinfo:
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: a search in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin return no convert binary either, i'm so confused.

Comment: Perhaps ImageMagick convert has been removed. Check `which -a convert`

Comment: which -a convert return no result

Comment: It would need to be listed in your PATH environment variable for `which -a convert` to find it.  Either it is installed in a private directory, such as /opt,  or it was removed after installing PHP Imagick.  Where is Imagick installed?

Comment: You can find lists of files here : https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=imagemagick . On my system /usr/bin/convert is a symlink to /etc/alternatives/convert and I also have multiple files with the suffix -im6.q16 like /usr/bin/convert-im6.q16

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `Imagick` extension binds `MagickWand` library -- which is a C-API to `MagickCore` library. On many distros, MagickWand & MagickCore libraries can be installed without the common CLI utility (e.g. `magick`, `convert`, `display` &tc).

You can review all the libraries linkled by running `ldd` on `imagick.so`.

```
$ ldd /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe7fea000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007faa2c6b5000)
    libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.7 => /lib64/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.7 (0x00007faa2c588000)
    libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.7 => /lib64/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.7 (0x00007faa2c2af000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007faa2c0a5000)
    ...
```